# Need help understanding the MOSFET trailing edge dimming

Tags: surge-protection, powermosfet, inrush-current, dimming, phase-detector

I am working on a circuit to control AC loads up to 1.5 kW by using MOSFETs ([FCHD125N65S3R0-F155](https://www.onsemi.com/pdf/datasheet/fchd125n65s3r0-d.pdf)).

The circuit:

[image]

I have a few concerns:

1. The current is flowing through the body diode of Q2 during the positive half of the cycle and the current is flowing through the Q1 body diode during the negative half of the cycle. There is so much power wastage happening i.e 1.2*6.25 = 7.5 W. Is there a better way to solve this issue?
2. Is there any advantage of using an IGBT and what will be the changes?
3. What are the R3, L3, and C3 values for over-current and over-voltage protection (VDS = 600V)?

Comment: We're missing the datasheet and part number of the MOSFETs. What does it tell you about \$ V_{gs} \$ for turn-on? Hit the [edit] link.

Comment: There is no way to get rid of the current flowing through the body diode. This is called reverse recovery. You can, however, switch to Silicon Carbide FETs which have 0 (or close to it) reverse recovery. They are much more expensive though. For the IGBT vs FET discussion you'd need to give your fsw, but stick with FETs lol

Comment: Both the mosfets will be on at a time but current has to go though the diode because current flow through the mosfet is Drain to source .

Comment: @mkeith I think that's worth an answer.

Comment: @Stiddily  can you suggest any Silicon Carbide FET that I can do some research on it and what about L,R and C values.

Comment: L3 is to protect from dI/dt protection

Comment: Please modify your schematic to show where the 240V supply is connected. Does it use GND? Are the two GND nets you show in your schematic the same? They have the same net name but they have different symbols so it is unclear. Also, please show where the 15V supply is grounded. I assume the negative (ground) terminal of the 15V supply is connected to the sources of the MOSFET's, but that is not clear. I am very concerned about the viability and safety of your circuit and your ability to implement it and test it safely.

Comment: @niks as for SiC diodes, I don't know enough about your application to recommend a specific FET, but the lack of reverse recovery is a physical property of the material. This article by ROHM has some good comparisons between Si and SiC: https://www.rohm.com/documents/11303/2861707/sic_app-note.pdf .

Comment: @Stiddily I have read the rohm application note .That's quite helpful thanks a lot but SIC mosfets are too costly, for example the cost of SCH2080KEC  is $36.That doesn't justify the design cost.Is there any better ideas to controls 1.5 KW load with minimal power losses? any suggestions on mosfet with less power loss?

Comment: Oh, I'm sorry @niks, I must've misunderstood. You're just trying to reduce switching losses? The use of a gate driver will turn your FETs on and off faster which will decrease switching losses. Or are you just looking for a better way to switch an AC load?

Comment: @stiddily I want to switch an AC load in both positivee and negativee half cycle.

Comment: I think the title of this question is unclear. Perhaps it should be "Using Series MOSFET Pairs to Control AC Loads".

Answer (score 1):

I designed and built something like this, but I used PWM to control the voltage to the load, and it required two pairs of MOSFETs to take car of the inductive energy. I only tested it on a fairly light resistive load on 120 VAC but it seemed to work OK. In fact, I may have tested it on a transformer. It was to make a solid state "Variac". Here is the circuit as simulated:

[image: PWM Vernier Simulation]

Here is the actual prototype:
[image: PWM Vernier Prototype]

And here are some scope images, showing input and output waveforms:
[image: PWM Vernier Waveforms]

Answer (score 0):

I have a lot of questions about your circuit and your answers have not really shed much light on my questions. There really does seem to be a major disconnect between what you expect and what you drew in your schematic. Maybe you can look at the picture I drew and let me know if it is correct, or if not, you can update it to make it correct.

Based on the schematic I can say with confidence that any time Q1 is on, Q2 will also be on and vice verse. This is because the gates are tied together, and the sources are tied together. So Vgs of Q1 will always be equal to Vgs of Q2. Vgs is the voltage that controls whether the MOSFET's are on or off.

[image]

Assuming the GND in your schematic is NOT connected to the AC GND (let me know if this is wrong!), then it is impossible for current to flow through the body diodes of either Q1 or Q2. The body diodes point in opposite directions and are in series. So when the MOSFET's are off there is no current path. And when they are on, the body diodes are shorted by the Rds of the MOSFET. MOSFET's are bidirectional devices. When they are "on," current can flow in either direction from drain to source or source to drain with the same low resistance.

As far as choosing values for R3, C3 and L3 goes, it is not clear what you are trying to accomplish with them so I am not able to assist with that.

Comment: I am using the MOSFET in Hard commutation where the MOSFET body diode conducts.

Comment: @niks can you modify your schematic to show where the 240V source and the appliance are connected with respect to circuit board ground?

Comment: does the schematic is clear  now ?

Comment: Yes much better! In that case I do not think that the body diodes will be forward biased, but I do worry that hard commutation will lead to over-voltage across the MOSFET's. I have not designed such high voltage and high power system, but I have some experience with relatively high current 50V systems using MOSFET's with hard switching. I will try to write more tomorrow.

Comment: I am trying to to control load upto 1.5KW @ 240V, any suggestions on mosfets helps me a lot .Thanks.What about dv/dt and di/dt solution?